# How To Go About Learning Tangut

Tags: characters, writing

I have tried to research this topic for many nights, but I cannot
find any resources. I know it's a very old but i've always been
intrigued by Tangut.

More specifically, i'd like to go about learning the script, rather
than the language (Although the language would be a nice bonus).
This may come off as ignorant, but I assure you i'm genuinely intereted

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Go to the Wikipedia list of Tangutologists (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Tangutologists) and pick out some publications of the researchers which interest you. Some of these publications might be in Chinese, Japanese, or Russian rather than English. Good luck!

Comment: It's sad that this interesting question is closed, but here's an introductory link about fundamental structural differences between Chinese and Tangut characters https://www.jstor.org/stable/4528440